# Removing rows of data that are almost duplicates with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am stuck with a problem trying to remove "almost duplicates" from a Pandas DataFrame. Short example below.

**I have this:**

```
NUMBER

0 682-21803-405

1 682-21803-420

2 682-21803-430

3 694-3561821-41-1

4 694-3561821-41-4

5 694-3561821-41-5
```

**And I want this:**

```
NUMBER

0   682-21803-405

3   694-3561821-41-1
```

I saw some people having similar problems where they used regex, but I can't figure out how to use it and I need help.

Comment: You need what is the "almost duplicates" first. For example, 694-3561821-41-5 and 694-3561821-43-9 are similar?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you research this? Where? If it didn't help tell us why. What did you try? If you didn't try, why not? If you did, what did you do? We'd like to see your minimal attempt to solve it. Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write a solution for you.

Comment: Hello, and thank you. I will think about to add more details about what I already tried in the future. In this case I just tried to keep the question clean and straight forward after not succeeding at all in my own attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the part to ignore is the last field after `-`, you can use a short regex to remove this part and slice the non duplicates:

```
df[~df['NUMBER'].str.replace('-[^-]+$', '', regex=True).duplicated()]
```

output:

```
             NUMBER
0     682-21803-405
3  694-3561821-41-1
```